# Can't obtain token from Reckon API - Returning SSL Error

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I haven't been coding for many years so please forgive me.  I'm trying to obtain a token from the **Reckon API** using the following code, but getting this error returned:

> "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

```
<?php
$code= $_GET['code'];
$url = 'https://identity.reckon.com/connect/token';
$auth_creds = "CLIENTID:CLIENTSECRET";
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic" . base64_encode($auth_creds));
$body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $code . 
'&redirect_uri=http://localhost';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response === false)$response= curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

I'm following the Reckon API oauth help docs: https://reckon.helpdocsonline.com/reckon-api-authorisation-services

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out.  I had to add this line of code:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
However I was then getting another error "{"error":"invalid_client"}"...
This was due to encoding my client ID and client Secret incorrectly.  But now that is fixed and I have my token and refresh token.

Comment: How did you change your encoding of Client Id and Secret. I'm getting the same invalid_client error